# cannot bind to the app.config that was added to the project of the script task

Tags: c#, ssis-2012

i'm trying to use app.config inside of task script of the ssis.
this is what i did :
1.added app.config and adding key and value under appsetting tag
2.adding system.configuration reference
2.adding this following code -

```
using system.configuration
string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["somekeyvalue"];
```

if I look into the ConfigurationManager.AppSettings list data , I don't see any data binded ,any advise on this?

Comment: Did you add a value to the KEY?  Did you open the config file with Notepad to see if setting was added?

Comment: Hi jdweng, you are giving here a good point, first of all its obvious that I added keys and values and i just don't get them in the collection of the configuration.appsetting, additionally if i were creating the app.config externally and attaching it to the project so maybe i will be able to link the collection correctly, i expected that the project is linking the path of the project as a default when you adding a new app.config to the project and not adding it from external path, any thoughts?